# Why blue background are used for special effects and What is difference between the blue and the green backgrounds?

Tags: effects

In many movies and TV series blue background is being used for giving special effects or for some kind of animations. So what makes blue color so special? **Which is better, blue or green backgrounds**?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [Why are movie scenes shot with green background?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52597/49)

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [What is the green background? (“green screen”)](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8568/49)

Comment: I'm not going to pass this of as an answer because it's from what I know. Green is used a lot more because it has the most contrast with the human skin. There are a lot more blue than green hues in a well lit actors' skin. The contrast is needed to make the seperation of the actor and the background a lot easier. Blue screen isn't a bad choice but we tend to key out actors more often than objects since we can cgi those just as easy as the background.

Answer (score 2):

Source [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Green-Screen-Why-is-a-scene-shot-in-green-background-for-animation-or-adding-special-effects):

> Green/blue screens are based on the idea of **chroma-keying**. The idea is
>   that a specific color is chosen and replaced by a different
>   color/background. So, a green colored background can be switched out
>   with a background of, let's say, a weather map.
>
> Technically speaking, the colors **can be gray, white, black, or purple**,
>   but **green and blue are used most often because they "stand out" the
>   best. I say "stand out" in the sense that since chroma-keying is
>   picking up a color and replacing it with a different image**, if a
>   weatherman was wearing a red tie while filming on a red screen, the
>   tie would be replaced as well as the background. In the
>   movie/weather/gaming industry, green and blue screens are used.
>
> **Blue screens are used in place of green screens because it's generally
>   easier to chroma-key**. The color is softer than in a green screen.
>   However, green screens are still more commonly used because of
>   multiple reasons. One of them being the fact that some people like to
>   wear **blue clothing**. Green screens are also more commonly used because
>   of the color **green being the highest luminance of all the color**
>   channels (RGB). Green screens are very bright, but because of the high
>   luminance, there is also a high level of **light reflection** from a green
>   screen, resulting in "green spill".
>
> **Green spill is when there is so much light reflection that some color
>   reflects onto your subject as well**. Green spill is very problematic,
>   and is usually best fixed before shooting by watching your lighting,
>   and chroma-key background.
>
> But, in the end the thing that determines the use of a blue screen
>   versus a green screen is foreground objects. It's not a **good idea to
>   shoot Kermit the frog in front of a green screen, and shooting an
>   "Avatar" character in front of a blue screen isn't a very bright idea
>   either.**   If you're shooting video or with a single-chip camera, be
>   aware of the component resolution of your camera.  Green is used with
>   video because traditionally it is stored at the highest resolution. 
>   Many of today's compression formats  store blue at the lowest
>   resolution.  **If your camera is recording 4:2:0, that means blue is 1/8
>   the resolution of green, which can lead to matte edge issues if you
>   try to key with blue.** If you're using a single-chip camera with a
>   bayer filter (probably all current single-chip cameras), green is
>   recorded at twice the resolution of blue or red.
>
> Single-chip cameras use a bayer pattern to record red, green, and blue
>   using a single sensor. A 4k single-chip camera records green at 2k,
>   red at 1k, and blue at 1k.

Comment: Oh dear, green spill indeed. Especially actors with a dark(er) skin. It helps to have a really big space but sometimes you have to do with a small studio and than have to deal with a lot of post work.